# Remove additional newlines from file output

Tags: ruby, file

I have a script that dumps data from a serial port to both a terminal and the harddrive. The output to the terminal looks fine, however the file write an ^M after each resulting in an extra newline for every other line.

The offending code:

```
# run and dump to file.
loop {
    # output data to log file.
    data = sp.read
    data.delete!("\C-M")   # Removes escape character.
    if( data != "" ) 
        puts data
        File.open($log_file, 'a') { |f| f.write( data ) }
    end
}
```

Example output:
On the terminal:

```
1
2
3
```

In the file

```
1

2

3
```

Edit: The solution is to run data.delete!("\C-M") after the read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your serial data looks like, but you can always do a chomp on data variable before writing. Try it and see how it goes.

Edit: If you want to remove the ^M, maybe you can try `sp.read.tr("\r","")`

Comment: Does not work. Is a commented below, the extra newlines are created by an ^M sequence. Chomp removes the final newline but does nothing with the other newlines in the received data.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the data written to the file in ruby with read. I suspect the problem you have is with the carriage return characters that sometimes cause problems when transferring a file from windows to linux or when downloading files via some mail clients.

Comment: I tried to open the output file in vim and can see that each line ends with a ^M character. Appearently some process sees fit to append a 'scroll down window one line' character to each line.

Comment: I figured it out and revised the question to reflect that. However your comment lead on the right path. Thank you.